# JQuery/Javascript - Loop through all json elements after and including value

Tags: javascript, jquery

It may seem like an odd request, though I am not too good with JQuery/Javascript and there is no documentation on how to do this certain thing a customer needed.

I have this array: ["Value1", "Value2", "Value3","Value4"] and he wants it so that if he clicks on a button to delete e.g. value2, value3 and 4 are also deleted (all elements after) and for html to be changed on each one (so I can not just delete everything after, as html has to be changed in the process too).

I'm familiar with .each but it being used in such a situation seems rather slow and given JQuery's popularity, I would assume there is a better alternative or at least a method of employment of .each than looping through them all and checking their keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here is a working jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aT3X8/1/**

Given:

```
var arrMyArray = ["Value1", "Value2", "Value3","Value4"];
```

First, get the `index` of the item the user is deleting. Say the user deletes the 2nd item (or whichever item is deleted will need to be passed into the `indexOf` in place of `Value3` so that we can get it's index:

```
var intIndex = arrMyArray.indexOf("Value2");
```

Now, loop thru the array, starting at the element they chose to delete:

```
for(i = intIndex; i < arrMyArray.length; i++){
    alert("I'm on item: " + arrMyArray[i]);
}
```